# Find which rows are not digits in specific DF column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe with 40 columns x 2.5 million rows (many financial securities)

`df['AMT_ISSUED']` is supposed to be integers but I am getting an error such as

```
 '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

when I try `df2 = df.loc[df['AMT_ISSUED']>=1]`

converting to int:`df['AMT_ISSUED'] = df['AMT_ISSUED'].astype('int64')`

I get: `invalid literal for int() with base 10:`

Maybe I have a very big number in there?

My question is how can I create a `df['IS DIGIT']` (true or false) using `isdigit()` function to start inspecting the data.

Comment: `df["AMT_ISSUED"].str.isnumeric()`? or force convert while ignoring errors using: `df["AMT_ISSUED"].astype(int, errors="ignore")`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```py
import numbers
df["IS_DIGIT"] = df["Date"].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, numbers.Number))
```

Comment: For my dataset i have an error:
'descriptor 'isnumeric' requires a 'str' object but received a 'float''

I assume its a float that python can't use .loc on.

Comment: @Sumit The answer is updated as per your comment.

Comment: @Amirhossien 
Very nice, it worked well Thank you!
I was able to locate the portion of the dataframe where theses error occurs. It turns out all of them are "0". Such a weird error! On to solving this issue!

Answer (score 0):

use apply with a custom function like this.

**Python 3.x**

```
def isdigit(x):
    return isinstance(x, (int, float, complex)) and not isinstance(x, bool)

df['IS DIGIT'] = df['AMT_ISSUED'].apply(isdigit)
```

**Python 2.x**

```
def isdigit(x):
    return isinstance(x, (int, float, complex)) and not isinstance(x, bool)

df['IS DIGIT'] = df['AMT_ISSUED'].apply(isdigit)
```

You can check how many non-numeric values are there in your dataframe by

```
df['IS DIGIT'].value_counts()
```

Also, note that **ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10** occurs when you convert the string or decimal or characters values not formatted as an integer.